# Selenium can not click on one element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am using Selenium Chromedriver and my problem looks like this:

1. My program is clicking element on website and a list of elements appear.
2. Than it is choosing one of element from list using checkbox.
3. Nextly it is trying to click other element but the program crashes.

When the mentioned list appear if I am clicking anywhere on website using inspect option the code of inspected element looking like this:

```
<div id="__selectOverlay" style="display: block;"></div>
```

how can I click any element from website after the list appear?

Answer (score 0):

looking at the html snippet shared, "__selectOverlay" might be the overlay which comes on top of the web page(like a loading spinwheel/panel) .

To get rid of the error, you can try the following
 * Wait for panel/overlay to disappear
 * Close the panel , if there is a panel close button.

And then click on any element on the web page

Comment: I have checked there is no button to close a listbox, also I have tried to use SEND_KEYS with few TABs method to jump to other element but it also does not work :(

Comment: more info required either share the code you are using or the screenshot /html source

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared the **`WebElement`** seems to me as a **`Overlay`** within a **`div`** tag. Moreover this **`div`** tag doesn't have a **`onClick()`** event associated. So we won't be able to click the `WebElement` straight away. Possibly you might be trying to invoke **`click()`** method on some other element which is having this **temporary / permanent Overlay** through the **`div`** tag.

### Solution

Depending on the type of **Overlay** there are two possible solutions as follows :

- **`Temporary Overlay`** :

  In this case induce **`ExplicitWait`** with  **`ExpectedConditions`** set to **`invisibilityOfElementLocated`** for the **Overlay** to be invisible.

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("ele_to_inv")));
  ```
- **`Permanent Overlay`** :

  Use **`JavascriptExecutor`** to send the **`click`** directly on the element.

  ```
  WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element_xpath"));
  JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
  ```

Comment: Unfortunatelly there is no element to .click() , I can use a refresh() method but all of my previously choosed options from this particular website will  disappear.

Comment: In your question you have mentioned **Nextly it is trying to click other element but the program crashes.** and **how can I click any element from website after the list appear?**

Comment: Yes :) , but I have check the XPATH of that element before I click the listbox. After I click() a ListBox , using inspect of html code  in everywhere on website I see, mentioned on the begining html code.